# Capturing traffic in the cloud

Tags: linux, networking, traffic, network-traffic

I am trying to work out a solution for capturing traffic in the cloud and currently running out of ideas. We need to capture traffic from servers in the cloud and send it to the sensor of the NTA (the sensor can be placed in the cloud). The cloud does not provide any means to capture and send traffic (like ERSPAN). There is currently no virtual appliance that can serve that purpose. We cannot purchase vTAP (budget issues), so I am relying only on opensource.

I was looking for some agents that can capture and send traffic from Linux (Debian-like) machines. All I found is Stenographer (from Google) that can capture and write to the disk. The problem is that I still need to send it. The sensor can accept traffic coming via GRE-tunnel.

The alternative is using virtual router (like Open vSwitch), but I feel like it will create more troubles than actually solve (management issues, several teams are involved in administration).

If there is anything you can suggest, I would be very grateful.

Comment: The standard tcpdump (https://www.tcpdump.org/) wont do the trick ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that Linux can in fact act as an ERSPAN source (example [taken from here](http://vger.kernel.org/lpc_net2018_talks/erspan-linux.pdf)):

```
ip link add dev myerspan type erspan seq key 30 \
  local 192.168.1.4 remote 192.168.1.1 erspan_ver 1 erspan 12
tc qdisc add dev eth1 handle ffff: ingress
tc filter add dev eth1 handle ffff: ingress matchall \
  skip_hw action mirred egress mirror dev myerspan
```

Setting up a router is an option, but Open-vSwitch sounds overkill – you can already turn a standard Linux VM into a router with *zero additional software*, having it forward traffic between e.g. an isolated "VPC" (if I have the terminology right) and Internet. The downside is that you'd still have to use the exact same packet capture methods (tcpdump and similar), although it still has advantages over in-server agents that it cannot be bypassed if someone gains root access to the servers.

---

I was also going to suggest `tcpdump`, the "original" packet capture tool that's probably installed everywhere, but it also has the downside that it'll only output a 'pcap'-format stream – you can pipe it through SSH, but it can't provide GRE/ERSPAN as output.

It wouldn't be difficult to create a libpcap-based tool that sends all captured traffic through GRE/ERSPAN, but after reading Stenographer's README and pondering the multi-Gbps traffic that Real servers apparently carry, decided against it.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to at least try this!